# Split oversized images when exporting to PDF

Tags: javascript, pdfmake

I am using pdfmake after html2canvas. I am turning a big chunk of html to image (canvas) and then this into pdf (because of very complicated styling in this html).

In case the canvas is longer than 1 page, I wish to show as much as I can on the 1st page, then on the 2nd to continue from where I stopped and etc. etc.

I was thinking of something like this:

```
var dd = {
   content: [
      {
         image: 'sampleImage.jpg',
         height: 1500,
         width: 500,
         margin: [0, 0, 0, 0]
      },
      {
          image: 'sampleImage.jpg',
          height: 1500,
          width: 500,
          margin: [0, -820, 0, 0]
      }
   ]
}
```

Expecting:
1st page: Part of the image (as much as it fits in 1 page)
2nd page: Different part of image (starting from where page 1 finished)
Result:
1st correct, 2nd page identical to 1st!

Surprisingly when I tried:

```
var dd = {
   content: [
      {
         image: 'sampleImage.jpg',
         height: 1500,
         width: 500,
         margin: [0, -820, 0, 0]
      },
      {
         image: 'sampleImage.jpg',
         height: 1500,
         width: 500,
         margin: [0, 0, 0, 0]
      }
   ]
}
```

Expecting:
2nd page: Part of the image (as much as it fits in 1 page)
1st page: Different part of image (starting from where page 1 finished)
Result:
Both pages correct but... wrong order!

Comment: What is the output you are expecting to have?

Comment: Ben can you please share code snippet for turning a big chunk of html to image (canvas)?